# Getting DataTables to not filter certain rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Currently, our generic DataTables integration allows us to filter for Users, Items, etc.

In the case of our User table, we have a column with a checkbox. When this checkbox is clicked, the User should ignore any table filtering.

Here's what we have in mind:

- We click the checkbox for say, two users
- We begin to filter for a user that is not checked
- The two checked users will stay in the table, as well as the user that was filtered for.

I wrote an implementation that simply appends the row back into the DOM if it's checked and not present, but it's pretty hacky. I would prefer an implementation that used tools offered by DataTables itself.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You should be able to use the DataTables API search function, which can accept a regex.  Then you could write the regex to look for the search value except ones that have a checked checkbox.   Haven't tried it, but it should be doable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to make rows with checked checkboxes persistent upon searching, you may implement your custom searchbar with [searching plugin](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Plug-in-structure) that would filter rows depending on whether it contains searched text **or** has checked checkbox within the row node:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push((_,__,rowIdx,dataObj) => Object.values(dataObj).some(cellData => cellData.toLowerCase().includes($('#searchbar').val().toLowerCase())) || $(dataTable.row(rowIdx).node()).is(':has(:checked)'));
```

Complete **DEMO** of this concept you might find over [here](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/oKGWEP?editors=0010).

Comment: Thank you so much! After some time to fit it into our project, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the problem. Here is the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  dataTable.on('search.dt', function() {

    $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().keyup(function(e) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      value = 'true|' + value
      //console.log(value);
      dataTable.fnFilter(value, null, true, false, true, true);
    })


  });
  $('table').find('tr').on('change', function(event) {
    //console.log($(this).index());
    //console.log(event.target.checked);
    if (event.target.checked) {
      $(event.target).attr('checked', 'checked');
      $(event.target).parent().append('<div id="true" hidden>true</div>');
    } else {
      $(event.target).removeAttr('checked');
      $(event.target).parent().find('div').remove("#haha");


    }
    //reload a specific row 
    // dataTable.api().row($(this).index()).invalidate().draw();
    //reload all row
    dataTable.api().rows().invalidate().draw();

  })





})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">

<style>
  thead input {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>checkbox</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```